# How can I add text to each top corner of a jQuery mobile collapsible

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to know how I could insert some text to the top right and top left side of a jQuery mobile collapsible. I don't know how to do that but I have done this so far and the text inside the < p >text at left corner < /p > tag doesn't even show up in the collapsible.

```
  <h1>Title</h1> 
<div data-role='main' class='ui-content' id='collapse'> 
<div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='b' data-content-theme='b' data-iconpos='right' data-expanded-icon='collapse' data-collapsed-icon='expand'> 
<p>text at left corner </p>

     <h4> <span id='collapstxt'> nenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. </span> <button href='#' id='bt01' data-icon='check' data-iconpos='right' style='width:100px;' onclick='alert(1);event.stopPropagation();' >Reply</button></h4>
<p> nenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. C <p>
</div></div>
```

This is what I've done so far in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t9zn770/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in JQM grid as an option

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a floatleft"><strong>I'm Block A</strong> and text inside will wrap</div>
  <div class="ui-block-b floatright"><strong>I'm Block B</strong> and text inside will wrap</div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
```

You can further define the alignment of each block if you want left align on block A and right align on block b

```
.floatright {
text-align:right;
}
 .floatleft {
text-align:left;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5j8ad80/1/

Comment: Thank you @Cory for your answer but I was wondering if is possible to have that text in the block before it gets expanded

Comment: Not sure what you mean by expanded

Comment: the text block you added is only visible if I click on the collapsible and then it expands and I see the two blocks of text each side but only if I click on it which is what I mean.

Comment: Ok I changed the text in the collapsibles so you can see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/n5j8ad80/3/

Comment: Ok that's good but now the text that was there now is gone :(